# How to append a div based on the content of a JSON Array information

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, ejs

I am working on an EJS view and I am trying to go through the "TYPE" array in a JSON file and if it contains "SOCCER", I want to append "This is a FOOTBALL GAME" and if not I want to append "This is not a FOOTBALL GAME" to the view. I would appreciate any assistance. Below is my code:

JSON DATA

```
 {
    barcode: "3999889",
    name: "Fifa ",
    brand: "Fifa 17",
    TYPE: [
    "SPORTS",
    "SOCCER",
    "ATHLETIC"
    ],

    }
```

result.ejs

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <strong><%= data.name %></strong>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <%= data.brand %>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <a href="/">Search Again</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the object type array contains soccer with "includes":

> const includesSoccer = yourobject.TYPE.includes('SOCCER');

Then in template you can check if (includesSoccer) // Do something